# Is this approch correct for receiving update from async method in watch in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a watch in Vuejs component where I set async method for tracking the updates and displaying the updated data:

```
watch: {

    getUpdates() {
     
      if (this.isReloaded) 
      
        this.getInfo()
      }
    },
    }
```

getInfo is the async method where I have api cals. I haven't noticed any updates in the data so not sure if this a correct approach. Can warch call async method in the above way and display update in the UI?

Comment: The properties under `watch` are supposed to refer to expressions you want to watch.  They are not like methods in the sense that you give one an arbitrary name.  Unless `getUpdates` refers to an expression in your code, the watch won't ever fire.  In other words, the name tells the watch what to watch.  Check [this example](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) in the docs and notice how the watch called `question` watches the data property with the same name.

Comment: @Dan The question is a bit different. There is another code related to watch and it works perfect. The only thing is questionable is that async method call inside watch called getInfo

Comment: Async is one of the primary reasons to use a watch over a computed, there's no issue there. What are you trying to watch for changes? If it's `isReloaded`, your format is wrong for the reason above.  Let me know and I can show you.  Otherwise, maybe you can show the working related code you mentioned.